How to create a standalone executable file from a MATLAB GUI for ARM Cortex-A (Rockchip - Orangepi 5 plus) Ubuntu device?
I have a MATLAB GUI (myGUI.m and myGUI.fig) that works perfectly on my laptop (both Windows and Ubuntu). I need to run this GUI on a Rockchip device (Orange pi 5 plus) with ARM Cortex-A (64-bit) processors, running Ubuntu 22.04.
Unfortunately, MATLAB cannot be installed on the Rockchip device, and there is also no MATLAB Runtime available for ARM-based architectures.
I have tried MATLAB Coder and codegen command to generate C/C++ code from a simple MATLAB function and created an executable on my laptop. I even cross-compiled for ARM, but codegen does not support MATLAB GUIs.
I also tried MATLAB Compiler, but the generated executables rely on the MATLAB Runtime, which isn't available for ARM processors.
I’m looking for a solution that allows me to run this GUI on the Rockchip Ubuntu system.
Ideally, I would like to package the entire MATLAB GUI as a standalone executable, but I am open to alternatives if this is not possible directly.
Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You've tried all the right steps I think, and unfortunately this isn't directly possible. As you've observed:

Using the "MATLAB Compiler" is only an option when you want to deploy to a system that is already supported by MATLAB itself
Using code generation doesn't support the UI elements of MATLAB

I can think of two broad strategies:

Use code generation to emit a shared library for the computational portion, and write a separate UI to drive the computation using whatever UI toolkit you choose
Use code generation as in step 1, and use some sort of network communication to drive it from your desktop MATLAB using the existing UI.

Unfortunately, both approaches require a chunk of work.
